# Setting the name of each cell to its content/value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

I'd like to create a macro that selects a rectangular range of cells and sets the name of every one of those cells to the value/contents of the cell.

In terms of what I've thought so far, I get an error though with the cell.Name line.

```
Public Sub NameCell()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:D1")
For Each cell In rng
    cell.Name = CStr(cell.Value)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Not every piece of text is a [valid name](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx#BMsyntax_rules_for_names).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
Sub setVal()
    Range("A1:C6").Select
    Selection = "value"
End Sub
```

Comment: How is that related to [assigning names to ranges](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx)?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: yeah, this wasn't exactly what I was looking for. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may work for you unless I also misunderstood the question.

```
Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set r = Sheet1.UsedRange

For Each cell In r
    Sheet1.Names.Add Name:=cell.Value, RefersTo:=cell
Next
```

Keep in mind, though, that you would want to check that the `cell.Value` is valid (no spaces, etc.) for a named range.

Answer (score -1):

To replace a range of cells with their values (removing any formulas from the range), you would use something like this.

```
Public Sub NameCell()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:D1")
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: How is that related to [assigning names to ranges](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx)?